# Assertion 's' failed at src/basic/cgroup-util.c:1852, function cg_mask_to_string(). Aborting 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, network-manager, systemd

#### systemd version the issue has been seen with

249.11-0ubuntu3.11

#### Used distribution

Ubuntu 22.04.3

#### Linux kernel version used

6.2.0-39-generic

#### CPU architectures issue was seen on

x86_64

#### Expected behaviour you didn't see

Expecting systemctl status to be usable without encountering any systemd-related issues.

#### Unexpected behaviour you saw

1. Periodically encountering the error `[system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)`.
2. After executing `sudo systemctl status abcabc`, I encountered the following error: `Failed to get properties: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)` or `Failed to get properties: Connection timed out`.
3. After executing `sudo reboot`, I encountered the following error: `Failed to open initctl fifo: No such device or address Failed to talk to init daemon.`

#### Steps to reproduce the problem

Occurs after running normally for a period of time.

#### Additional program output to the terminal or log subsystem illustrating the issue

```sh
1月 02 15:28:51 zsqk-pc-01 snapd[803]: storehelpers.go:773: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "bare", "core20", "core22", "gnome-3-38-2004", "gnome-42-2204", "gtk-common-themes", "snap-store", "snapd", "snapd-desktop-integration"
1月 02 15:29:14 zsqk-pc-01 systemd[1]: Reloading.
1月 02 15:29:14 zsqk-pc-01 systemd[1]: Assertion 's' failed at src/basic/cgroup-util.c:1852, function cg_mask_to_string(). Aborting.
1月 02 15:29:59 zsqk-pc-01 systemd[1]: Caught <ABRT>, dumped core as pid 113634.
1月 02 15:29:59 zsqk-pc-01 systemd[1]: Freezing execution.
1月 02 15:30:00 zsqk-pc-01 systemd-oomd[623]: Failed to connect to /run/systemd/io.system.ManagedOOM: Connection refused
1月 02 15:30:00 zsqk-pc-01 systemd-oomd[623]: Failed to acquire varlink connection: Connection refused
1月 02 15:30:00 zsqk-pc-01 systemd-oomd[623]: Event loop failed: Connection refused
1月 02 15:30:01 zsqk-pc-01 CRON[113644]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
1月 02 15:30:01 zsqk-pc-01 CRON[113645]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
1月 02 15:30:01 zsqk-pc-01 CRON[113644]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
1月 02 15:30:24 zsqk-pc-01 dbus-daemon[784]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
1月 02 15:30:24 zsqk-pc-01 snapd[803]: taskrunner.go:299: [change 8 "Mount snap \"firefox\" (3600)" task] failed: systemctl command [daemon-reload] failed with exit status 1: Failed to reload daemon: Connection reset by peer
1月 02 15:30:50 zsqk-pc-01 dbus-daemon[784]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```